# How to repackage a Visual Studio Code extension into a Che-Theia plug-in with its own set of dependencies

Tags: plugins, containers, eclipse-che

I am trying to repackage a Visual Studio Code extension into Eclipse Che as a Che-Theia plug-in.
The [plug-in](https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-defect-prediction-plugin#how-to-use) extracts source code metrics from Ansible files, as shown below:

[image]

It does so by executing a command-line of a tool written in Python, namely [ansiblemetrics](https://pypi.org/project/ansiblemetrics/), that must be installed on the user's environment.
Therefore, I cannot add that dependency to the VSC extension's package.json. Rather, the user has to install it on the Eclipse Che workspace. Nevertheless, I want that Eclipse Che users do not need to install the dependencies when using the extension. A container looks the way to go.

I have the following Eclipse Che DevFile

**Eclipse Che DevFile**

```yaml
apiVersion: 1.0.0
metadata:
  name: python-bd3zh
attributes:
  persistVolumes: 'false'
projects:
  - name: python-hello-world
    source:
      location: 'https://github.com/che-samples/python-hello-world.git'
      type: git
      branch: master
components:
  - type: chePlugin
    reference: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radon-h2020/radon-plugin-registry/master/radon/radon-defect-predictor/latest/meta.yaml'
    alias: radon-dpt
```

The [Eclipse docs](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/end-user-guide/what-is-a-che-theia-plug-in/#vs-code-extensions-and-eclipse-theia-plug-ins_che) says "To repackage a VS Code extension as a Che-Theia plug-in with its own set of dependencies, package the dependencies into a container."
Containers can be added in the chePlugin reference's metadata under the [`spec` keyword](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/end-user-guide/publishing-metadata-for-a-vs-code-extension/):

```yaml
spec:
  containers:                                                   
    - image:                                                    
      memoryLimit:                                              
      memoryRequest:                                            
      cpuLimit:                                                 
      cpuRequest:
```

Therefore, my plugin's metadata ([meta.yaml](https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-defect-prediction-plugin/blob/master/meta.yaml)) is as follows:

**meta.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v2
publisher: radon
name: radon-defect-predictor
version: 0.0.5
type: VS Code extension
displayName: RADON-h2020 Defect Predictor
title: A Defect Predictor for Infrastructure-as-Code by RADON
description: A customized extension for analyzing the defectiveness of IaC blueprints
icon: https://www.eclipse.org/che/images/logo-eclipseche.svg
repository: https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-defect-prediction-plugin
category: Other
spec:
  containers:                                                   
    - image: stefadp/radon-dpt-plugin
  extensions:
    - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radon-h2020/radon-defect-prediction-plugin/master/radon-defect-predictor-0.0.5.vsix
```

where the image [stefadp/radon-dpt-plugin](https://hub.docker.com/r/stefadp/radon-dpt-plugin) was built upon the following Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install ansiblemetrics
```

However, when I run the workspace in Eclipse Che, I observe the following error:

```
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-plugin-metadata-broker:v3.4.0"
Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-plugin-metadata-broker:v3.4.0"
Created container
Started container
Starting plugin metadata broker
List of plugins and editors to install
- radon/radon-defect-predictor/0.0.6 - A customized extension for analyzing the defectiveness of IaC blueprints
- eclipse/che-workspace-telemetry-woopra-plugin/0.0.1 - Telemetry plugin to send information to Woopra
- eclipse/che-machine-exec-plugin/7.24.2 - Che Plug-in with che-machine-exec service to provide creation terminal or tasks for Eclipse Che workspace containers.
- eclipse/che-theia/7.24.2 - Eclipse Theia
All plugin metadata has been successfully processed
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-theia-endpoint-runtime-binary:7.24.2"
Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-theia-endpoint-runtime-binary:7.24.2"
Created container
Started container
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-plugin-artifacts-broker:v3.4.0"
Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-plugin-artifacts-broker:v3.4.0"
Created container
Started container
Starting plugin artifacts broker
Cleaning /plugins dir
Processing plugin radon/radon-defect-predictor/0.0.6
  Installing plugin extension 1/1
    Downloading plugin from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radon-h2020/radon-plugin-registry/master/radon/radon-defect-predictor/0.0.6/radon-defect-predictor-0.0.6.vsix
Saving log of installed plugins
All plugin artifacts have been successfully downloaded
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-jwtproxy:0.10.0"
Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-jwtproxy:0.10.0"
Created container
Started container
pulling image "stefadp/radon-dpt-plugin"
Successfully pulled image "stefadp/radon-dpt-plugin"
Created container
Started container
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-workspace-telemetry-woopra-plugin:latest"
Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-workspace-telemetry-woopra-plugin:latest"
Created container
Started container
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-machine-exec:7.24.2"
Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-machine-exec:7.24.2"
Created container
Started container
pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-theia:7.24.2"

Error: Failed to run the workspace: "The following containers have terminated:
nt0: reason = 'Completed', exit code = 0, message = 'null'"
```

Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize your docker image to work in the sidecar container. As an example you can take a look at images which are already used in Che in sidecars: https://github.com/eclipse/che-plugin-registry/blob/master/CONTRIBUTE.md#sidecars

Try to create next structure:

```
radon
  etc
    entrypoint.sh
  Dockerfile
```

The content of `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
set -x

USER_ID=$(id -u)
export USER_ID
GROUP_ID=$(id -g)
export GROUP_ID

if ! whoami >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "${USER_NAME:-user}:x:${USER_ID}:0:${USER_NAME:-user} user:${HOME}:/bin/sh" >> /etc/passwd
fi

# Grant access to projects volume in case of non root user with sudo rights
if [ "${USER_ID}" -ne 0 ] && command -v sudo >/dev/null 2>&1 && sudo -n true > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    sudo chown "${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}" /projects
fi

exec "$@"
```

and the `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV HOME=/home/theia

RUN mkdir /projects ${HOME} && \
    # Change permissions to let any arbitrary user
    for f in "${HOME}" "/etc/passwd" "/projects"; do \
      echo "Changing permissions on ${f}" && chgrp -R 0 ${f} && \
      chmod -R g+rwX ${f}; \
    done

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install ansiblemetrics

ADD etc/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ${PLUGIN_REMOTE_ENDPOINT_EXECUTABLE}
```

Then build this Dockerfile and use it in your plugin `meta.yaml`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it does not really help. That source explains how to publish the plugin on Che (as built-in). I simply want to add my plugin as third-party. It is straightforward by defining the meta.yml file. However, if I avoid using dependencies and, thus, containers, it works fine. The problem arises when I add the 'containers' section in the metadata, which is allowed, but I am probably missing something.

Comment: I've updated my comment, hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! Can you please modify your answer and add #!/bin/sh at the first line of entrypoint.sh? So that users using this answer do not have to face with following error: standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"